# Loading images for canvas object asynchronously

Tags: node.js, fabricjs

I'm on fabric 3.4 in a node environment.
I am trying to load and create during the loading of an existing canvas.

The way it works, is I have an existing fabric stored as json, which has a `rect` object in it that acts as a placeholder for an image. So when the canvas is loaded, and image location is provided so that it can replace the existing `rect` object with the same size and position.

I think I'm pretty close, though any documentation for loading images without a url  seems to be very outdated. These are local files, not available by any url.

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
const Canvas = require('canvas');

var canvasobj = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, { 
  height: 1000, 
  width: 1000 
});

let template = JSON.parse(data);//data is canvas json

canvasobj.loadFromJSON(template, () => {
  canvasobj.renderAll();
}, 
(o, object) => {
     if(object.stitch.type === 'portrait'){//identifier for placeholder
         const c = Canvas.createCanvas(2304, 3456)
         const ctx = c.getContext('2d')

          Canvas.loadImage(binds.image).then((image) => {
              ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 0, 70, 70)

              fabric.Image.fromURL(c.toDataURL(), (img) => {
                  canvasobj.add(img)
                  canvasobj.remove(object);//remove the placeholder
              }
         }
     }
}
...
```

I *think* this method will work. But the problem I'm having is `Canvas.loadImage` is asynchronous, and this reviver that runs on each object is not. The revivers get run, and then the callback that renders the canvas gets called before the image has loaded. If I make the reviver `async` and `await` the image loading, this dons't change anything, since nothing is waiting for the reviver to resolve.

Is there a way to get this method to work?
Is there a different way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only issue is that you need to wait for all the revivers, you can just create an empty array and push a new `Promise` each time the reviver is called. Resolve each of those promises when your async image load is done. In the meantime, call `Promise.all()` and wait for the whole async stuff to end. The revivers themselves seem to be called synchronously, so by the time your script reaches `Promise.all()`, you'll have all those promises in the `Pending` state.

```
const promiseArray = []

canvasobj.loadFromJSON(template, () => {}, 
(o, object) => {
  const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
   //...
    Canvas.loadImage(binds.image).then((image) => {
      //...
      fabric.Image.fromURL(c.toDataURL(), (img) => {
        //...
        resolve()
      })
    })
  })
  promiseArray.push(p)
})

Promise.all(promiseArray)
  .then(() => {
    // ...
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an async function from a callback based method using a Promise.

```js
async function fabricImageFromURL(image_url) {                                                                          
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {                                                                        
    try {                                                                                                               
      fabric.Image.fromURL(image_url, function (image) {                                                                
        resolve(image);                                                                                                 
      });                                                                                                               
    } catch (error) {                                                                                                   
      reject(error);                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                   
  });                                                                                                                   
}
```

then you can use it in your `async` function using `await`:

```js
async function doingMyStuff() {

  const image = await fabricImageFromURL(image_url);

  // here image is already loaded
}
```